# convert data rows in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe wherein the data has this format

```
data = {
  "Born": ['November 9, 2000 (age22)', 'July 15, 2001, (age 21)'],
}
```

I would like to transfer this data to only show the age as int, e.g.

```
data = {
  "Born": [22, 21],
}
```

First of all, is that doable and if so, how would I go about it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and convert to integer with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Born'] = df['Born'].str.extract('\(age\s*(\d+)\)', expand=False).astype(int)
```

Updated dataframe:

```
  Born
0   22
1   21
```

##### regex

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lRk2VY/1)

```
\(       # match a literal (
age\s*   # match "age" with optional spaces
(\d+)    # capture digits
\)       # match a literal )
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation. Really helpful!

Comment: @quarantinho You're welcome. I see that you changed the accepted answer a few times, note that you can only accept one

Comment: Yes, I saw that. It's unfortunate, because both of you were helpful. What's the socially accepted standard here?

Comment: @quarantinho you chose whatever you feel is the best/most complete/most helpful. [Here is a relevant discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255150/how-to-choose-between-multiple-correct-answers). The choice is yours only ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for digits after `age` with optional space:

```
df['Born'] = df['Born'].str.extract('age\s*(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
print (df)
   Born
0    22
1    21
```

Comment: This solution has worked for me! Thank you